# Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to print props of a react component but getting an error. Please help:

**Snippet:**

```
<!-- DOCTYPE HTML -->
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://fb. me/JSXTransformer-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <!-- gap above is intended as else stackOverflow not allowing to post -->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div1"></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">

        //A component
        var George = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div> Hello Dear!</div>
                    <div>{this.props.color}</div>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<George color="blue"/>, document.getElementById('div1'));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting "Hello Dear!" and then next line "blue". But, I am getting this error instead.

**Error:**

[image]

Comment: Please post your error as well.

Comment: Done bro ......

Comment: Just noticed that there's an error in the error. Should be "JSX" not "XJS"...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### React v16 and later

As of React v16 React components can return an array. This was not possible prior to v16.

Doing this is simple:

```
return ([  // <-- note the array notation
  <div key={0}> Hello Dear!</div>,
  <div key={1}>{this.props.color}</div>
]);
```

Note that you need to declare a key for each element of the array. According to official sources, this *might* become unnecessary in future versions of React, but not as of right now. Also don't forget to separate each element in the array with `,` as you would normally with an array.

#### React v15.6 and earlier

React Components can only return *one* expression, but you are trying to return two `<div>` elements.

Don't forget that the `render()` function is exactly that, a function. Functions always take in a number of parameters and always return exactly *one* value (unless void).

It's easy to forget, but you're writing JSX and not HTML. JSX is just a syntactic sugar for javascript. So one element would be translated as:

```
React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello Dear!');
```

This gives a React element, which you can return from your `render()` function, but you cannot return two individually. Instead you wrap them in another element which have these `div`s as children.

From the [**official docs**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components):

> **Caveat:**
>
> Components must return a single root element. This is why we added a `<div>` to contain all the `<Welcome />` elements.

---

Try wrapping these components in another component so that you only return *one*:

```
 //A component
    var George = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (
              <div>
                <div> Hello Dear!</div>
                <div>{this.props.color}</div>
              </div>
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<George color="blue"/>, document.getElementById('div1'));
```

Comment: In html standards you can not put a div in a span

Comment: i'm working with react fiber, get same error  the code:  return ([
      <div class="iconsgvcontainer"><IconFlight> </IconFlight>Vuelos</div>
      <SectionContent></SectionContent> ]);

Comment: @stackdave You forgot the commas. You are returning an array so separate each element  normally.

Comment: This literally saved my day

Answer (score 3):

Issue is you are returning more than one html element from render method, here:

```
return (
      <div> Hello Dear!</div>
      <div>{this.props.color}</div>
);
```

**React v16+ solution:**

React 16 included a new element [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), by help of that we can wrap multiple elements, and no dom node will be created for Fragment. Like this:

```
return (
      <React.Fragment> 
            Hello Dear!
            <div>{this.props.color}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
);
```

or return an array:

```
return ([
            <p key={0}>Hello Dear!</p>
            <div key={1}>{this.props.color}</div>
]);
```

**React v < 16:**

Wrap all the elements in a wrapper div, like this:

```
return (
      <div> 
            Hello Dear!
            <div>{this.props.color}</div>
      </div>
);
```

**Reason**: A React component can't return multiple elements, but a single `JSX` expression can have multiple children, You can only return one node, so if you have, a list of `divs` to return, you must wrap your components within a div, span or any other component.

One more thing, you need to include the reference of babel also, use this reference in header:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
```

Check the working example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <!-- gap above is intended as else stackOverflow not allowing to post -->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="div1"></div>

    <script type="text/jsx">

        var George = React.createClass({
            render: function(){
                return (
                    <div> Hello Dear!
                       <div>{this.props.color}</div>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });

        ReactDOM.render(<George color="blue"/>, document.getElementById('div1'));

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

With **React 16** we can return multiple components from `render` as an array (without a parent div).

```
return ([
    <div> Hello Dear!</div>,
    <div>{this.props.color}</div>
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your returning DOM in a single html element.

Try this

```
return (
    <div>            
        <div> Hello Dear!</div>     
        <div>{this.props.color}</div>
    </div>     
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (  <div>
                <div> Hello Dear!</div>
                <div>{this.props.color}</div>
         </div>
            );
```

Hi, elements inside return should be wrapped by something. Just add  as shown above and should work ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Render function should only return one root element try this

//A component

```
var George = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                <div> Hello Dear!</div>
                <div>{this.props.color}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact your problem is that you try to render several elements at the same time what is not possible in this version of react,

**reason**
render it is a function and by nature a function returns only one value

but with **react-fiber** you can do what you do, to correct your problem there are two solutions :

Either **use a wrapper** for both of your elements

```
    var George = React.createClass ({
         render: function () {
           return (
                <div>
                  <div> Hello Dear! </div>
                  <div> {this.props.color} </div>
                <div>
               );
           }
    });

ReactDOM.render(<George color = "blue" />, document.getElementById ('div1'));
```

The second solution is to **return a array** with both of your elements

```
var George = React.createClass ({
      render: function () {
          return ([
              <div key='0'> Hello Dear! </div>,
              <div key='1'> {this.props.color} </ div>
          ]);
      }
});

ReactDOM.render (<George color = "blue" />, document.getElementById ('div1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Enclose everything you are using in return statement inside another div tag.

```
render: function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <div> Hello Dear!</div>
                    <div>{this.props.color}</div>
                </div>
            );
        }
```